# Using two python functions boto3 in a single AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to write two functions in a single AWS Lambda function. currently, Lambda triggers the function using the handler in case I have two functions in my code then how to change it so that the Lambda handler can execute both the functions.

I have found this. However, it is using if statement. In my scenario I will have to run both the functions one after the other and also pass the output of 1st function to the 2nd function. Thanks 
[How to have more than one handler in AWS Lambda Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687152/how-to-have-more-than-one-handler-in-aws-lambda-function)

Here is the sample code:

```
import boto3' import json' from datetime 
import datetime REGION = 'us-east-1' 
emrclient = boto3.client('emr', region_name=REGION) 

def lambda_handler(event, context): 
EMRS = emrclient.list_clusters( ClusterStates = ['STARTING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING'] ) 
clusters = EMRS["Clusters"] 
    for cluster in clusters : 
    ID = cluster.get("Id") 
    EMRid = emrclient.list_instance_groups( ClusterId = str("ID") ) 
    print(EMRid)
```

Comment: Please provide the codes for others to have a better picture of your question. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say what the best solution is without more information on your use case, but [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) are designed to handle running multiple lambdas with data passed between them in a robust way (retries, parallelization, etc).

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@tturnbull/passing-data-between-lambdas-with-aws-step-functions-6f8d45f717c3) provides a good overview, though the code in the example is JavaScript rather than Python.

Comment: Thanks Bwest really appreciate your help. 

I have a sample code here and I understood how to use it in the same function. But need help in sending the ID output to the list_instance_groups.

Comment: Here is the sample code:

import boto3'
import json'
from datetime import  datetime

 REGION = 'us-east-1'

emrclient = boto3.client('emr', region_name=REGION)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 EMRS = emrclient.list_clusters(
   ClusterStates = ['STARTING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING']
 )

 clusters = EMRS["Clusters"]

 for cluster in clusters :
  ID = cluster.get("Id")
  
  EMRid = emrclient.list_instance_groups(
  ClusterId = str("ID")
  )
  
  print(EMRid)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional function to achieve what you have listed as an example. That said, assuming that you need to add additional processing/functionality on the instance_groups dict, you can start here. This should work, if you have 50 clusters or less:

```py
import boto3
import json
import datetime

emrclient = boto3.client('emr', region_name='us-east-1') 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    EMRS = emrclient.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING'])
    for cluster in EMRS['Clusters']:
        emr_inst_grp_work(cluster['Id'])

def emr_inst_grp_work(cluster_id):
    """Get instance group details dict for given cluster id"""
    inst_dict = emrclient.list_instance_groups(ClusterId = cluster_id)
    print(inst_dict)
    # ADD code for additional dict or cluster work/processing here
```