# How to filter API Gateway requests for the java lambda based on the request path

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function with API Gateway proxy integration, meaning it accepts proxy+ resources as input.

I have a java Lambda class that accepts [APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent.java) type as Input and gives [APIGatewayProxyRequestOutput](https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-java-libs/blob/master/aws-lambda-java-events/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/runtime/events/APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent.java) as response/output.

```
public class DashboardOrchestratorHandler implements RequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {

    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context) {
        
        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        response.setIsBase64Encoded(false);
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "text/html");
        response.setHeaders(headers);
        response.setBody("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>AWS Lambda sample</title></head><body>" +
                "<h1>Welcome</h1><p>Page generated by a Lambda function.</p>" +
                "</body></html>");
        // log execution details
        //Util.logEnvironment(event, context, gson);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now I'm looking for some guidelines on how to orchestrate different classes based on the request path and request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple handlers -> https://forum.serverless.com/t/multiple-handlers-per-function/1025/2 but you can have multiple helpers that can be triggered depending on the event.
Here is the Python example -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688766/1737811 but it's pretty straightforward to translate it to Java or any other stack.