# How do I call my Lambda function from SQS when I am already using exports.handler on awsServerlessExpress? (nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-serverless

I want my SQS to call my Lambda function whenever it has a message in it. I've seen people use something like `exports.handler` to handle events from SQS. However I am using `exports.handler` in my `lambda.js` file like this:

```
// lambda.js
'use strict'
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./index')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => { awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context) }
```

To my knowledge, AWS only allows you to define one handler per Lambda function. Is there any code I could put inside my `index.js` file that could act as an event handler for SQS?

I've tried to add a handler in `index.js` and that didn't work. My AWS Lambda function is configured for `lambda.handler`.

Comment: You cannot add a second handler, but why don't you simply create a second lambda that handles the SQS Event?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687152/how-to-have-more-than-one-handler-in-aws-lambda-function